# Unable to instantiate activity ClassNotFoundException is thrown, when I try to run the app after moving activity in a separate library/

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing app for both tv and mobile. And now I need to share the components between two platforms. I moved MainActivity to a seperate library module. And now it crashes on start:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{nl.glukadevice.seniorapp/nl.glukadevice.seniorapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "nl.glukadevice.seniorapp.MainActivity"
```

I tried to clean all Gradle cashes and rebuild the project and it doesn't help.

I included the module into build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':shared')
}
```

Here is how it's declared in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
                android:name="nl.glukadevice.seniorapp.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

More info needed. Is your activity truly moved or just the file? By that I mean if there is correct package in the file.

Also, I'd put also the regular **android.intent.category.LAUNCHER** to your intent-filter categories. 
Do you use in your manifest this feature?

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="false" />
```

Last but not least - try to invalidate the cache in ***File > Invalidate Caches/Restart***